# MainActivity theme NoActionBar but fragments still showing NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to hide the Toolbar so I can put my own one in but the toolbar still shows, could someone help please. The theme `@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar` works in other activities.

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Style:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val fireStoreInstance: FirebaseFirestore by lazy { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }
private val currentUserDocRef: DocumentReference
    get() = fireStoreInstance.document("users/${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
            ?: throw NullPointerException("UID is null.")}")
internal lateinit var helper: RealmHelper
internal lateinit var realm: Realm

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Realm.init(applicationContext)
    val defaultConfig = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .build()
    realm = Realm.getInstance(defaultConfig)
    helper = RealmHelper(realm)
    fireStoreInstance.collection("users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .currentUser?.uid.toString()).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            AppConstants.USER_ROLE = task.result["role"].toString()
        }
    }
    val list = helper.retrieveAT()
    if (list.count() <= 0) {
        fireStoreInstance.collection("assessmentType").get().addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val list = ArrayList<AssessmentType>()
                for (document in task.result) {
                    val u = AssessmentType(document.id,document.get("Desc")!!.toString())
                    helper.save(u)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    this.replaceFragment(PeopleFragment())
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_chat -> {
                this.replaceFragment(PeopleFragment())
                true
            }
            R.id.navigation_modules -> {
                this.replaceFragment(ModuleFragment())
                true
            }
            R.id.navigation_timetable -> {
                this.replaceFragment(TimetableFragment())
                true
            }
            R.id.navigation_profile -> {
                this.replaceFragment(MyAccountFragment())
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("CommitTransaction")

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment)
            .commit()
}
```

}

Screen:

[image: toolbar]

Comment: You can use parent style as **"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"** in your activity style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in every app...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide your action bar by using below piece of code

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your theme is incomplete which would be like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

In above style `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` is what you need to solve your issue.

---

So your style must be

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```